# Repeat pattern to 1024x768 php

Tags: php, html, css, image, design-patterns

I have an image with dimensions 100x100 pixels, it is a seamless pattern png.

How do I tile it to the dimension 1024x768 pixels with php?

Comment: why do you need to use php?  Couldn't you use javascript with css?

Comment: @thepristinedesign I do think there are valid use cases of this, e.g. generating a background for user-supplied PNGs. But if it's only about the standared background of a website, I agree.

Comment: @Steve: Your question is a bit broad. It's understandable what you would like to achieve in general, but it's unclear where/how you would like to achieve it. Posting the code you've got so far often is a first pointer. Additionally you can just share a bit more information what you would like to do, e.g. repeat the pattern with CSS or create a new PNG image or whatever. It's just that it's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use php, it's not such a big deal with GD:

```
$file = imagecreatefrompng("pattern.png");
$newFile = imagecreatetruecolor(1024, 768);

for($i = 0; $i <= 1024; $i += 100) {
  for($j = 0; $j <= 768; $j += 100) {
    imagecopy($newFile, $file, $i, $j, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}

imagepng($newFile, "pattern-1024.png");
```

If you can use HTML and CSS:

```
.pattern {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  background: url("pattern.png") repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that you want the HTML page to display your pattern repeatedly. If that's the case, it is not done by PHP but by CSS. You could use a rule such as:

```
body
{
background-image:url('yourpattern.png');  
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: steve asking to repeat the image fully of the window(1024 x 768). not repeat - y.

Comment: Good point, I have updated the answer.

Comment: lol? if I would like to use css, I will use it. I want to generate an actual image with dimensions 1024x768

Comment: Next time ask proper questions if you want proper answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions (see [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php)).